# Difference in code on javascript for .append()/.after() on IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Is there another function that could be used in place of .append() or .after() where it would be written the same way for IE10+ and Chrome66+

**Right now the code:**

Works in Chrome but not IE:

```
document.getElementById('label_upload').after("label text here");
```

Works in IE but not in Chrome:

```
$('#label_upload').after("label text here");
```

Comment: are you sure the first one works - nevermind, I see it's something ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after check the compatibility table and the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after#Polyfill)

Comment: And sure second does? The selector `$('label_upload')` is not valid

Comment: One of the easiest solution for is to use polyfill for `.append`, MDN suggests one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Polyfill

Comment: @charlietfl Oh sorry let me update what I had, it was #label_upload

Comment: @JaromandaX Is there a better function to use to not have to polyfill? Though,  since there is no choice, will try the polyfill

Comment: polyfill would be the best option, since then you don't have to worry about IE being based on 20 year old standards

Comment: Alright, thanks so much! I'll try out polyfill.